# rsync ignores anchored exclude pattern

Tags: rsync

I do the following:

```
rsync --recursive --delete --delete-excluded --exclude-from=$HOME/etc/rsync_exclude.txt --relative --safe-links --executability . /path/to/savedir
```

Note that the source directory is the working directory (specified as `.`)

Inside the working directory, I have a directory `./repository` and a file `./Vagrantfile`.

The file `rsync_exclude.txt` contains, among others, the lines

```
/repository/
/Vagrantfile
```

I would have expected that these entries would exceed my `repository` and `Vagrantfile`, because

- the leading slash expresses that the names are to be anchored at the root directory for saving, which is the working directory, and
- the trailing slash on *repository* explicitly states that this is a directory, not a file

However, both entries are copied.

What did I do wrong?

*(This is rsync 2.6.9 running on MacOS Sierra (but I don't think this matters in this case)).*

UPDATE:

When debugging rsync (using `-vv` and --dry-run) I can clearly see that all non-anchored rules are accepted (for instance, rsync tells me *hiding directory vp5/.git because of pattern .git/*), but none of the anchored rules work. I also tried to replace the source directory (.) by ./ or $PWD, but this too did not have any effect.

Furthermore, when I remove the leading / (for instance, turning /repository/ into repository/), the directory is excluded. Of course this directory would now be excluded **anywhere** in the tree, which doesn't harm in this particular case, but is not what I want in general).

Comment: Does this change if you use `./` in place of `.`?

Comment: You might get some hints on how your filter works with `--debug=FILTER2`

Comment: This should work. Run `rsync -vv …` to see what decisions it makes. Check that your file doesn't have any stray whitespace or invisible characters, such as carriage returns (Windows line endings don't work outside Windows).

Comment: `--relative` doesn't really add value if your source directory is `.`. You might want to include `--times` or even `--archive` in your set of options so that `rsync` can more easily detect that a file doesn't need to be recopied.

Comment: @meuh : According to the man page, there is no --debug option. For debugging, the man page suggests `-vv`, as also Gilles mentions it in its comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda : No, this does not change anything.

Comment: @Gilles : See my update in my posting.

Comment: I suggest you create a small example that is modeled from your real case and that you _post the output of the entire transaction_ here. With vague hints about what happened you won't get much beyond hand-waving.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with `rsync` version 3.1.2:

```
$ ls -F
archive/  backup/  mk-archive.sh*  mk-backup.sh*  mk-cloud.sh*  mk-source.sh*  source/

$ cat /tmp/excludes
/archive/
/backup/
/mk-archive.sh
/mk-backup.sh

$ mkdir -p /tmp/target
$ rsync --relative --recursive --delete --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/tmp/excludes . /tmp/target/

$ ls -F /tmp/target
mk-cloud.sh*  mk-source.sh*  source/
```

What's happening here is as described in the man page for `rsync`, so your patterns must be anchored to `/` immediately at the start of the copy (i.e. under `.`).

> **ANCHORING INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS**
> As mentioned earlier, global include/exclude patterns are  anchored  at  the  "root  of  the  transfer" [...].
>
> Because  the matching is relative to the transfer-root, changing the trailing slash on a source path or changing your use of the `--relative` option affects the path you need to use in your matching (in addition to changing how much of the  file tree is duplicated on the destination host). [...]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> cd /home; rsync -a --relative me/foo you/ /dest
> ```
>
> +/- pattern: `/me/foo/bar`      (starts at specified path)
> +/- pattern: `/you/bar/baz`     (ditto)
>
> Target file: `/dest/me/foo/bar`
> Target file: `/dest/you/bar/baz`

You can see the exclusions being acted upon by adding `-vv` (or `--verbose --verbose`) to the `rsync` command.